# Laravel API not found inside wordpress

Tags: wordpress, laravel, api

I am new to web development and even though i have looked around I am still stuck with this part which is to manage to make my api run on a server. Locally it runs perfectly but once I add my api inside my server it just says not found whenever i attempt to access it.

This is the folder structure

```
-www
--wp-admin
--wp-content
--wp-includes
--ProjectApi
---app
---bootstrap
---config
---database
---public
----index.php
----.htaccess
---resources
---routes
---storage
---tests
---vendor
```

Locally i would just say http://localhost/ProjectApi/public/api/v1/hello and this would call my api and do its function. But once it was added to the server when i do http://randomServerName.com/ProjectApi/public/api/v1/hello It just gives me a 404 not found error.

Comment: well probably you need to remove the public part? It's recommended to put just the public folder in the web root and the rest 1 lvl up.

Comment: If you control `randomServerName.com` you can make a subdomain `api.randomServerName.com` and then a vhost from that subdomain that points to `/www/ProjectApi/public` so you can do `api.randomServerName.com/api/v1/hello`